# while using wsimport in maven , i am getting exception like Connection timed out: connect.

Tags: java, maven, soap, xsd, wsdl

by using wsimport from command prompt i am able to generate the java code successfully as well as from maven project in eclipse.
while using wsimport in maven  for some wsdl's, i am getting  exception like below
[ERROR] IOException thrown when processing "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd". Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.

Answer (score 0):

wsimport task cannot obtain XSD schema for source generation from URL http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd

Possible reasons: network issues, security regulations, temporary failure on the remote host etc. 
The easiest way to check connection: just try to get this XSD from browser on the same machine on which you start wsimport task (works for me now, I can see this schema)

Comment: i am able to browse the xsd ...but while using the maven i am not able to get the same.      the same wsdl , i am  able to convert as java source by using command prompt  :  >wsimport -keep -s src ~~WSDL~~

Comment: parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] IOException thrown when processing "file:/D:/practice2/WSDL2Java/src/wsdl/onvif.xsd". Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\practice2\WSDL2Java\src\wsdl\onvif.xsd (The system cannot find the file specified).